# Oracle SQL Query one row with monthly value only, but need to group it by month

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I can't figure out the correct query on Oracle SQL 
I have the following data:

```
Name    Monthly_amount   Start_date 
Bob     100              April 2014
Mike    120              June 2014
Steve   80               Sept 2014
Bob     50               Dec 2014
```

And I would like to get the following result

```
Name |Jan-14| Feb-14| Mar-14| Apr-14 |May-14| Jun-14| Jul-14 |Aug-14|Sep-14|Oct-14| Nov-14| Dec-14
Bob   0       0       0       100     100    100      100     100    100    100     100      150 
Mike  0       0       0       0       0      120      120     120    120    120     120      120 
Steve 0       0       0       0       0      0        0       0      80     80      80       80
```

Comment: Is the `start_date` column declared as a `DATE` or a `VARCHAR2`?

Comment: You need to look at a pivot query.

Comment: i'm not familiar with oracle but have you tried the docs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should work for you. If you need the column definitions to be dynamic, you would have to create it dynamically, but it's better to do that kind of things in your application.

```
SELECT Name,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Start_date <= TO_DATE('01-JAN-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')
      THEN Monthly_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Jan14,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Start_date <= TO_DATE('01-FEB-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')
      THEN Monthly_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Feb14,
(etc.)
FROM table1
GROUP BY Name;
```

(This assumes `Name` uniquely defines a person)

Comment: Think it at least needs a `sum` to take care of Bob's extra 50 in December?

Comment: thanks, your solution works like a charm.
is there an easy way to add a sum as a last line, to sum up all the month?